# Current closure reason is not valid anymore - should I do something?

Tags: discussion, support, review-queues, vote-to-reopen

I was doing reviews for the reopen queue, and I encountered a question that had been edited. The closure reason was initially *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself"*. The question had been edited to include code, but it was now clearly too broad.

What should I do in such situation where the original closure reason is no longer valid, but question should be closed for another reason?

Comment: I wouldn't bother re-opening it. Imo, the semantics of the closure reason are less important than the fact it's put on hold. Maybe leave comment explaining it's too broad now.

Comment: I agree with Cerbrus.  Having the correct close reason is important but if the question was off topic for reason X, gets edited, and is now off topic for reason Y we can just leave it closed as X.  Otherwise it takes 5-10 people to reopen and close the question for the right reason.

Comment: How one can provide valid MCVE and make question too broad? Are you 100% sure it was not just edited to include code dump?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov It could have been too broad all along, and just also been missing a reproducible example.  Or perhaps adequately describing what the actual problem with has disambiguated the question to realize just how much it's actually asking about, where before it simply wasn't clear.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov can't recall what the question was anymore (there isn't a way to find a skipped review, is there?) - but that particular question was just an example, I'm looking for guidelines to handle any question that has invalid close reason.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't bother re-opening it.

The semantics of the closure reason are less important than the fact it's put on hold. Just leave it closed if the reason it should be closed changes.

Maybe leave comment explaining it's too broad now.